# How to execute a simple SQL command within MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Probably a super basic question but I have an SQL Command:

```
ALTER TABLE `staff` ADD `uhnw` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Ultra High Net Worth, 0...No, 1...Yes' AFTER `comments`;
```

Can I place this command anywhere in the "query" section?

[image]

Thanks...just want to be 100%

Comment: Yep that should be fine. Did you try it? If you're unsure you can always back your database up first. Or try out the command on a test database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Please see the attached link.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-query-panel.html